# Why does adding a dependent variable to a MANOVA remove significance?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, manova, dependent-variable

We designed an experiment with 2 discrete independent variables (IV), 1 (measured) confounding variable, and 2 dependent variables (DV). We hypothesize that the two IVs interact on both DVs.

Right before the experiment, we decided to add another DV, because it is commonly measured in our field, seemed cheap to collect, and we didn't really have any argument towards why not.

Now, after the experiment, we found that running the 3-way MANOVA on the 3 DVs leads to a non-significant result (according to Wilk's Lambda); however, the originally designed experiment with the 2 DVs (ignoring the added DV) shows a significant 3-way interaction, as predicted.

I'm a little torn about how to interpret these results. On the one hand, the experimental psychologist in me wants to not ignore any collected data, out of fear of being hit with the p-hacking bat. However, the data scientist in me wants to remove an apparently unimportant feature (the third DV), since there is no strong theoretical motivation to have it in the first place, other than "well people often measure that".

How should I deal with the added measurement? Run two analysis one 3-way MANOVA with 2DVs, and 1 3-way ANOVA on the added DV? Report it as a null result using 3DVs in one MANOVA?

Why does a significant MANOVA suddenly become non-significant when adding more dependent variables? (If you measure more things, then your effect will disappear doesn't sound logical to me)

Comment: @MichaelM I'm not sure I understand. It's not about adding covariables, but outcome measures. It's like saying "Height differs by gender, but if we also measure eye color between genders, there is no more difference in height", and I don't understand where the error in my logic is.

Comment: oh, I see. That is a different story. Removed my comment.

Comment: might it help if we could see the results? (and possibly the data structure)